# Installing K8s on vSphere results in multiple VMs using Juju

Tags: juju, vmware, conjure-up, kubernetes

During the installation, I configured it to deploy 1 master and 2 worker nodes but I'm seeing a total of 10 VMs all together.

[image: Juju VMs]

There are 3 VM's that are configured with the exact specifications I defined during the installation. The last VM in this list is configured with 4GB of memory while the remaining are configured with 1GB of memory.

After the installation completed, I ran `kubectl get nodes` and am only seeing 2 nodes total in the cluster. Perhaps I need to open an issue.

```
NAME            STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
juju-366554-6   Ready    <none>   12m   v1.16.1
juju-366554-7   Ready    <none>   12m   v1.16.1
```

Resource wise, it's not a problem for my ESXi host; however, would like to clean them up if they aren't necessary. I don't see any documentation explaining what they are used for.

Comment: Are you sure those are not used by K8s? There are etcd nodes, mayble a load balancer and stuff. It is not only a K8s master / worker vm. The VM with the name `juju-75de15-0` is probably your juju controller that you bootstrapped when installing juju. `juju status` will show more info.